# Object of type super class not able to access method of Sub class

Tags: java

```
    class A extends B
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        B obj = new A();
        obj.speak(); //error :the method speak() undefined for type B
    }

    public void speak()
    {
        System.out.println("in speak");
    }
}

class B {
}
```

I am a beginner in java and i am not able to understand what does this line `B obj = new A();` mean. Why can't A access its own method. Please explain in detail if class A is instantiating then why its methods are not accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following statement `B obj = new A();` means two things.

1. `obj` is declared as an object of type `B`.
2. `obj` is defined by `A`.

In other words, you can use `obj` as you would use any other `B` object. By declaring it's type to be `B` you restrict the compiler to use only that perspective (and of `B`'s super-classes).

So what does defining `obj` using `A` mean?

Using `A`'s constructor to build `obj` will cause every super-class of `A` to be constructed (From the first parent down), and every time methods are defined they override those that were defined by their super-class.

Member variables / static fields will only shadow those of the super-class, meaning that by switching perspective you can access different fields. However, it is crucial to remember that the methods will always be the ones that were defined by the last sub-class who defined them.

**code example**

```
public class Example
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    System.out.println(animal.name);
    animal.makeSound();
    Animal doggy = new Dog();
    System.out.println(doggy.name);
    doggy.makeSound();
  }
}

public class Animal {
  public String name;

  public Animal() {
    name = "NameLess";
  }

  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("What am I?");
  }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {

  public Dog() {
    name = "Goofy";
  }

  public void makeSound() {
    System.out.println("woof woof!");
  }
}
```

The output of this example will be:

```
NameLess
What am I?
Goofy
woof woof!
```